# Can you identify this inlet valve/fitting for me and what the corresponding male fitting is? I want to use it to dispense liquid only when connected

Tags: valve, fitting

[image]

I am trying to find more of these inlet valve/fittings but I do not know what this type of connection is called. I have seen it with a male fitting on a tube that connects to it to dispense liquid.

Comment: Not sure of the name, but will be a quick connect with auto shut off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A google search of "panel mounted quick connect with auto shut off" yielded several results. A search of reverse osmosis water filter fittings also showed various sizes and connectors. I just gave a few details of search criteria  as you didn't list material types or sizes you were interested in.

Answer (score 0):

The part on the right is a [Quick Disconnect Tube Coupling.](https://www.mcmaster.com/products/tube-couplings/connection-style%7Equick-disconnect)  This one appears to have a threaded connection mated with a matching hose barb.

The hose barb inside the container is, um, interesting.  What happens there?

If you want to dispense to a hose when connected you would get a matching male coupling with a hose barb, and I would have expected just a nut on the inside of the container.

Doesn't seem like a great arrangement, disconnection will result in a mess even if the female connector shuts off.

Comment: Hope the opening on top is big enough for a hand to get in.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is a dyi I picked up at a trade show, is there a better way to achieve this? I am looking to have this container filled with cold brew (so yes the barb inside is unnecessary). Then there is a hose that would come from a cold brew nitro dispenser that is drawing the liquid from the container.

Comment: Hydraulic quick connects for hoses shut off both ends/connects.  Only a small amount at/in the connection leaks out.

Comment: @crip659 nice catch, I see the plug and socket can both be had with or without shutoff.  Nice. So I guess you just use a rag to disco.